# Why does the ".where" method not filter through my List object?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, where-clause

I have written the following code for a Movie Review application I am developing. The Movie class has a few boolean properties to confirm whether or not the movie is of a particular genre, for instance, isRomantic.

However, the following code fails to display only the romantic movies, for instance, and simply displays all the movieNames.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is it that I'm doing wrong?
2. Assuming the below code and the intended functionality mentioned above is all I want the app to do, how efficient / optimised would you say my code below is? I am new to Dart and would love some feedback.

Thank you.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Movie> movieList = listOfMovieObjects().where((isRomantic) => true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: createListOfMovieItems(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> createListOfMovieItems() {
    List<Widget> myList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) {
      myList.add(buildMovieItem(movieList[i], i));
    }
    return myList;
  }
}

class Movie {
  String movieName;
  bool isRomantic;
  bool isComedy;
  bool isAction;

  Movie({this.movieName, this.isRomantic, this.isComedy, this.isAction});
}

List<Movie> listOfMovieObjects() {
  return <Movie>[
    Movie(movieName: '1', isRomantic: true, isComedy: true, isAction: false),
    Movie(movieName: '2', isRomantic: false, isComedy: false, isAction: true),
    Movie(movieName: '3', isRomantic: false, isComedy: true, isAction: true),
    Movie(movieName: '4', isRomantic: true, isComedy: true, isAction: true),
  ];
}

Widget buildMovieItem(Movie movie) {
  return Center(
    child: Container(
      child: Text(
        movie.movieName,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 80.0),
      ),
      height: 100.0,
      width: double.infinity,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on your code `where((isRomantic) => true)` "isRomantic" is the name that you assign to the current element, not the bool property, and the function always return true, thats why you are getting all the movies.

Also .where returns a lazy iterable, you should use .toList() method to get the filtered list.

Try this:

```
List<Movie> movieList = listOfMovieObjects().where((m) => m.isRomantic).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!
When you say `.where((m) => m.isRomantic)`, you are defining a new argument called m, right?

Comment: Exactly! when you iterate over the collection m is the current element (movie) on the iterable, so the function test each element based on isRomantic property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Movie> movieList = listOfMovieObjects().where((movie) => movie.isRomantic).toList();
```